# Work, Energy, and Power- Hooke's Law & graphing

Tags: forces, energy, work, power, displacement

The purpose of the work, energy, and power lab is to demonstrate the validity of Hookes Law over a limited range of displacements, measure the spring constant of several springs, and determine the work done in stretching a spring with a non-constant force. 
I have completed the experiment and got the information for my data tables ( Mass, Force, and Displacement) of 5 different springs. We added different mass increments to each spring. Now I'm stuck on determining the spring constant (k), and the work, and graphing the results.
k= f/displacement
work= f* displacement
I have done 5 trials for each springs, so I don't understand if I am suppose to calculate the spring constant and work for just one of the trials of each spring, or average it out, or what. I am really confused on this lab. I can't figure out how to graph the results.

Comment: The spring constant doesn't depend on the mass attached to it. It may depend in some extreme cases only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: use the formula you have and think about what its graph means. For Hooke's Law, this is what you have (ignoring signs/directions):
$$
F = kx
$$

You can see that if you were to use the data you have to graph force as a function of displacement, the graph would be a line whose slope is $k$. You can use the data points you have to create this graph either in Excel or by hand and measure the slope.